# Can anyone help me find this sci-fi/horror movie with guys backpacking and an invisible alien?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, science-fiction

I have very little to go on, as I saw this movie when I was very young. Here is what I remember.

- I believe it was an American made movie; most likely a low budget straight to video. I'm thinking it was from the 80s, or maybe the early 90s.
- I remember two or three guys backpacking for the weekend. I believe the setting was in the American southwest. It was not like a heavy forest, but more of a desert atmosphere. There was maybe a bit of Navajo/Native American motif in there.
- I believe they encounter an alien/monster. There are really only two things I can remember about it. For most of the movie, I believe that when they showed the alien, it was from the perspective of the alien. I don't believe you saw the alien until the end. I believe it also had a cloaking/invisibility power; but I'm definitely not thinking of *Predator*.
- I always remembered one of the leads to be Ed Harris, but it's not him, from looking through his filmography.

Comment: I don't know why, but I immediately think of "Fishing Naked". The Alien isn't invisible, nor shown from its perspective, of memory; but it is constantly referenced, but only really seen, at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["High Desert Kill" (1989)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097504/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

From IMDb:

> Like every year, **Jim, Ray, Brad and Paul leave the town for a week to
>   go hunting in the woods.** But this year everything is different:
>   There's not a single animal to be found, the whole forest has fallen
>   quiet. Two female campers they meet have mysteriously disappeared the
>   next day, leaving their whole equipment behind. And then they start to
>   behave weird themselves... An alien power is using them for cruel
>   psychological experiments.

Trailer:

You can watch the complete movie here:

It is an obscure, **low budget**, made-for-TV movie, **made in 1989**, which **was only distributed on VHS**. There is an alien in the movie, it disguises itself as a human and and we see the **alien's "first person" perspective** many times throughout the movie (at 0:02:38, for example). The movie opens with **two native American hunters** encountering with the alien presence.